# i want to fetch this information form that array php?

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
Array
(
    [found] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1400
                    [name] => ?Â¨?Â§?Â³Uâ€¦ U?UË†?Â³U? ?Â´UË† ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â­Uâ€žUâ€š?Â© ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â³?Â§?Â¯?Â³?Â© - ?Â¬UË†?Â¯?Â© ?Â¹?Â§Uâ€žU??Â© ?Â±UË†?Â§?Â¨?Â· Uâ€¦?Â¨?Â§?Â´?Â±?Â©
                    [visits] => 46
                    [shortdes] =>  ?Â¨?Â§?Â³Uâ€¦ U?UË†?Â³U? ?Â´UË† ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â­Uâ€žUâ€š?Â© ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â³?Â§?Â¯?Â³?Â© - ?Â¬UË†?Â¯?Â© ?Â¹?Â§Uâ€žU??Â© ?Â±UË†?Â§?Â¨?Â· Uâ€¦?Â¨?Â§?Â´?Â±?Â© - ???Â­Uâ€¦U?Uâ€ž Uâ€¦?Â¨?Â§?Â´?Â± ?Â¹Uâ€žUâ€° ?Â§UÆ’?Â«?Â± Uâ€¦Uâ€  ?Â³U??Â±U??Â±
                    [photo] => http://www.msrstars.com/up//uploads/images/msrstars.com63451f7ada.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1399
                    [name] => Uâ€¦Uâ€š?Â§?Â±Uâ€ ?Â© ?Â¨U?Uâ€  ?Â§Uâ€ž?ÂµUË†?Â± ?Â§Uâ€ž??Uâ€° ?Â§?Â³???Â¹?Â·U? ?Â¨Uâ€¡?Â§ ?Â§Uâ€žU?Uâ€¡UË†?Â¯ ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â¹?Â§Uâ€žUâ€¦ ?Â¨?Â§?Â«?Â±Uâ€¡ :: UË†?Â§Uâ€ž?Â´?Â¹?Â¨ ?Â§Uâ€žU?Uâ€ž?Â³?Â·U?Uâ€ Uâ€° U??Â­?Â¯?Â« Uâ€¦?Â¹?Â§Uâ€¡ Uâ€ U??Â³ ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â§?Â­?Â¯?Â§?Â« UË†Uâ€žUÆ’Uâ€  Uâ€ž?Â§ ?Â§?Â­?Â¯ U????Â­?Â±UÆ’
                    [visits] => 56
                    [shortdes] =>  Uâ€¦Uâ€š?Â§?Â±Uâ€ ?Â© ?Â¨U?Uâ€  ?Â§Uâ€ž?ÂµUË†?Â± ?Â§Uâ€ž??Uâ€° ?Â§?Â³???Â¹?Â·U? ?Â¨Uâ€¡?Â§ ?Â§Uâ€žU?Uâ€¡UË†?Â¯ ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â¹?Â§Uâ€žUâ€¦ ?Â¨?Â§?Â«?Â±Uâ€¡ :: UË†?Â§Uâ€ž?Â´?Â¹?Â¨ ?Â§Uâ€žU?Uâ€ž?Â³?Â·U?Uâ€ Uâ€° U??Â­?Â¯?Â« Uâ€¦?Â¹?Â§Uâ€¡ Uâ€ U??Â³ ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â§?Â­?Â¯?Â§?Â« UË†Uâ€žUÆ’Uâ€  Uâ€ž?Â§ ?Â§?Â­?Â¯ U????Â­?Â±UÆ’
                    [photo] => http://www.msrstars.com/up/uploads/images/msrstars.com3a442679e4.jpg
                )
```

i want to fetch that

```
[id] => 1400
                        [name] => ?Â¨?Â§?Â³Uâ€¦ U?UË†?Â³U? ?Â´UË† ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â­Uâ€žUâ€š?Â© ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â³?Â§?Â¯?Â³?Â© - ?Â¬UË†?Â¯?Â© ?Â¹?Â§Uâ€žU??Â© ?Â±UË†?Â§?Â¨?Â· Uâ€¦?Â¨?Â§?Â´?Â±?Â©
                        [visits] => 46
                        [shortdes] =>  ?Â¨?Â§?Â³Uâ€¦ U?UË†?Â³U? ?Â´UË† ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â­Uâ€žUâ€š?Â© ?Â§Uâ€ž?Â³?Â§?Â¯?Â³?Â© - ?Â¬UË†?Â¯?Â© ?Â¹?Â§Uâ€žU??Â© ?Â±UË†?Â§?Â¨?Â· Uâ€¦?Â¨?Â§?Â´?Â±?Â© - ???Â­Uâ€¦U?Uâ€ž Uâ€¦?Â¨?Â§?Â´?Â± ?Â¹Uâ€žUâ€° ?Â§UÆ’?Â«?Â± Uâ€¦Uâ€  ?Â³U??Â±U??Â±
                        [photo] => http://www.msrstars.com/up//uploads/images/msrstars.com63451f7ada.jpg
```

and list it as

```
list($id,$name,$visits,$shortdes,$photo)
```

so for that example when i `echo $id;`

it gives `1400`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [extract](http://php.net/extract):

```
foreach ($array['found'] as $value) {
    extract($value);
    echo $id;
}
```

But **you should access the array indexes directly**, **instead of injecting variables in the code**. After all, that's what arrays are for:

```
foreach ($array['found'] as $value) {
    echo $value['id'];
}
```